# How to add some text in all pages of an application

Tags: c#, asp.net

This question is asked by someone in an interview.
I have one application which have 50000 Asp.net web forms, 10000 html pages and 20000 asp pages.
I want to add something in all pages after body tag how can i achive this

Comment: write a C# program that take all webfiles(authorized) in a directory. use regex to find the required position of document and add tags in it

Comment: Is it useful when something is not in header/body and just after it? Well if it is, then read files through C# or VB.NET and use XML libraries to find relevant positions and add some text in it.

Comment: There is an ASP.NET / IIS pipeline with several options to 'filter' the response stream. The inclusion of HTML and ASP is an indication they want you to find (name) the lowest level handler.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the trick by a Custom HttpModule

**Module c#**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
public class HelloWorldModule : IHttpModule
{
    public HelloWorldModule()
    {
    }

    public String ModuleName
    {
        get { return "HelloWorldModule"; }
    }

    // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
    // events by adding your handlers.
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
        application.EndRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, 
         EventArgs e)
    {
    // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
    // request and response properties.
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension = 
            VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx") || fileExtension.Equals(".html") || fileExtension.Equals(".asp"))
        {
            context.Response.Write("<h1><font color=red>" +
                "HelloWorldModule: Beginning of Request" +
                "</font></h1><hr>");
        }
    }

    private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension = 
            VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".aspx")|| fileExtension.Equals(".html")|| fileExtension.Equals(".asp"))
        {
            context.Response.Write("<hr><h1><font color=red>" +
                "HelloWorldModule: End of Request</font></h1>");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**

As commented by @Andreas there are two distint pipeline to precess asp classic and aspx, so the HTTP module can't do the trick with .asp pages, probably only with an ad hoc [ISAPI filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa279373(v=vs.60).aspx) can work every request, but generally there is not used for writing an header to all web pages

Comment: Afair this won't work for Classic-ASP pages as .Net and Classic-ASP use different pipelines (aspnet_isapi.dll versus asp.dll). An ISAPI Filter would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>

and to restore <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>

Comment: yep this can do the trick, but I would not answer in this way in a technical interview for sure

Comment: Yes but I wanted to advice this, because the owner of the question is using Classic-Asp. So this method can achive that. I'm also using this kind of replace operations, in my own usage...